# View Ember App on Remote Server

Tags: ember.js, remote-server

I'm attempting to develop an ember.js app. All the required tools (node, ember-cli, bower, etc.) are installed on a remote machine. I can create the app with no problems, and run the ember server, but am unable to access the app through the browser on my local machine. The ember server appears to run on localhost:4200, meaning I would have to view it in the browser on the remote machine. Does anyone know how to open this up to being viewable outside localhost? I have a firewall setup on the remote machine, and configured it to allow connections on port 4200. I also have configured the hosts file on my local machine so that I can access content served from the remote server using the server's hostname instead of an ip address. I've been using `$hostname:4200` to try to access the app, but the connection doesn't go through. To the best of my knowledge, the remote machine isn't accessible outside of the network it's on (my local machine and the remote machine are on the same network). I've also used the `--proxy` option for `ember serve`, but that didn't work.

Essentially, does anyone know of a way I can view the app through the browser from my local machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to see Ember application served by `ember s` command on other machine in the same network by using IP of the other machine and correct port. I just had to use correct IP.

You can go to `cmd.exe` on Windows, then run `ipconfig` and then use IPv4 Address + ember port.

In my case it's:

http://192.168.x.xx:4200

And I can view it on other machine.

Comment: I had been doing this, to no avail. It turned out I apparently had the firewall on the remote machine not properly configured (tried adding a rule directly with ufw when I should've just stuck with using gufw on the machine). I can view it now; thanks for replying!